# How can I type the rounded parentheses on Overleaf

Tags: math-mode

[image]

Any code for this type of rounded parentheses I will highly appreciate.

Comment: Any news? Does one of answers is close to what you after?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\[
N = \left\lgroup\begin{matrix}
                -\frac{1}{2}    &   0           \\
                        0       &   -\frac{1}{2} \\
                \end{matrix}
    \right\rgroup
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for this equation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{math}
N=\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{1}{2}&0\\
0&\frac{1}{2}\\
\end{pmatrix}.
    \end{math}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks,albeit different in the middle since is more curved,i'm also getting the same output